# React DatePicker Not showing the selected date in useState

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I have a code that should show the calendar so that user can pick the date :
Problem is the useState is not picking the selected date.

Please help me. Below is my code:

```
import 'react-modern-calendar-datepicker/lib/DatePicker.css';
import DatePicker from 'react-modern-calendar-datepicker';

export default function PostCreateForm(props) {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(startDate);  // I cannot see the date I selected from the calender
    };

 return (
        <form className="w-100 px-5">
            <h1 className="mt-5">Create A New Project</h1>
            <div className="mt-4">
                <label className="h3 form-label">Project Due Date</label>
                <div>
                <DatePickern selected={startDate}  onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
                </div>
            </div>

            <button onClick={handleSubmit} className="btn btn-dark btn-lg w-100 mt-5">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `value` prop. See the [docs](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#props) for a complete list of available props.

For example, here is a `DatePicker` initialized with today's date as the default value:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())

<DatePicker
    label="Basic example"
    value={date}
    onChange={(newValue) => setDate(newValue)}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />} />
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally made it work ...